# bluetooth GATT over BLE for iOS and Android?

Tags: csr, gatt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project that needs iOS/Android APP to communicate with embedded side via Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) to transfer small amount of data. My embedded side is CSR chip which supports the dual mode.

Does anyone know is that possible for both Android and iOS to support this GATT over BLE? Any fee like joining developer program?
I think Android side should be OK, but I am very new to iOS and don't know it is easy to do so.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes Android supports GATT over BLE.  Yes iOS supports GATT over BLE.  Yes Apple requires you to be an Apple Developer in order to develop iOS apps and it costs $99/year.  You will also need an Apple computer to do the development.